# Mismatch in Total Records found and Database items

Tags: php, magento-1.9

In a custom module I created in Magento 1.9, I met an issue with the "Total records found" in the Grid created.

[image: 566 records found]

As in the image attached it's showing "Total 566 records found". But on searching my database tables which is responsible for displaying data here is completely empty. I tried to flush my cache and re-indexed in index management. Still the issue persisted. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: The code please...

Comment: Hi @RendyEkoPrastiyo It was working fine earlier. On using the same module I met with an issue that the custom tables are not getting created. After re-installing the tables are created. After that issue this 566 records issue came up

Comment: You mention custom table, which mean there are lines of code that handle the custom table, like Project\Module\InstallSchema, Project\Module\InstallData, and the controller which responsible for querying and displaying the table. That's what I mean.